# How to protect my applock's data

Tags: android, security, password-protection

I am implementing an application - "applock" which permits user to protect an other application from incompetent person in android phone. I don't know how to protect data of my "applock". In present, everone can easy to clear all data by accessing "Setting" --> "Application manager" --> choose my application and "Clear data". After that, all my data gone and my "applock" is useless.
I tried with FacelockforApp free version ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facelock4apps&hl=vi ) and it has same problem.
So, what can I do to fix this problem?
Thank in advance!